# Ubuntu 15.10 Wont Boot

Tags: boot

As soon as I turn my laptop on it shows Toshiba and then goes straight to Grub2.

When I tell it to boot Ubuntu (Or anything at all) It will go through this list of processes. There is only ONE fail and it is:

```
[Failed] Failed to start Login Service.
See 'systemctl status systemd-logind.service' for details.
```

I really LOVE Ubuntu!!!

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the world's greatest, but this has saved my bacon more than once.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have no access to another PC and my Ubuntu does not boot at all